# AH00112: Warning - Centos 6 / Apache 2.4 / Django 1.9 / mod_wsgi 3.5 / python 2.7

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have a dedicated server with GoDaddy.  I seem to have successfully set up everything properly but I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this issue:

When I restart apache:

```
[root@sXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX /]# /scripts/restartsrv httpd
```

I get this:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/local/apache/var/www/<my_django_project>] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/local/apache/var/www/<my_django_project>] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/local/apache/var/www/<my_django_project>] does not exist
```

I never specified a path of `/usr/local/apache/var/www/<my_django_project>` ???

It seems to just append my `var/www/<my_django_project>` to `/usr/local/apache` ... not sure why

My httpd.conf file:

```
... a bunch of pre configured goDaddy stuff I'm guessing here ...


LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/apache/extramodules/mod_wsgi.so
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.X:80>

ServerName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
# DocumentRoot /public_html/
ServerAdmin admin-noreply@mysite.com

Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/<my_django_project>/static/favicon.ico

Alias /static /var/www/<my_django_project>/static
<Directory /var/www/<my_django_project>/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /var/www/<my_django_project>/media
<Directory /var/www/<my_django_project>/media>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess <my_django_project> python-path= /var/www/<my_django_project>:/var/www/<my_django_project>/<my_django_project>:/var/www/<my_django_project>/<my_django_project_site>:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup <my_django_project>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/<my_django_project>/<my_django_project>/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/<my_django_project>/<my_django_project>>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

... more stuff already in the conf file ...
```

When I go to `XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX:80` in my internet browser it told me it can't find .htaccess file.  But now it's just redirecting me to http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:

It was pointed out that `AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/local/apache/var/www/<my_django_project>] does not exist` was due to not adding `/` in front of path.

My browser now gives me:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Is this through python runserver command or does this command work?

Comment: @JC203 When I use python2.7 manage.py runserver 0:8000 it works just fine.   But Apache is not able to server the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would indicate you have set `DocumentRoot` directive somewhere in your Apache configuration files to a path that does not have a leading slash. When that occurs Apache will append the path to the end of the `ServerRoot` directory which in your case is `/usr/local/apache`. Make sure that all your file system paths you set up are absolute path names with  leading slash.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out.  But I didn't realize that "AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot" was a past warning in the log, I don;t think it's related to the automatic redirect to http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Comment: What rewrite rules or redirect directives are in your configuration file. Also check for ``AddHandler`` rules for the ``.py`` extension as they could be interfering.

Comment: Apparently the redirect had to do with my browser caching.  I switched a different browser and it gives:

Comment: "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: I would guess it isn't even picking up that ``VirtualHost`` at all and using the default ``VirtualHost`` (first in configuration). You should not be using an IP address for ``ServerName`` as wouldn't match name based virtual hosting. And also not necessary to have IP in ``VIrtualHost`` directive itself. Would use ``*:80``.

Comment: the default httpd.conf file has multiple <virtualhost> and has comments of: "# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.  IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE PLEASE USE THE INCLUDE FILES."  ...so I added the <VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost> in an include conf file.  Would it be better to replace the <VirtualHost *:80> found in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: If you are going to leave the existing virtual hosts alone, you must access your site using a host name, not an IP address. That host name must be what ``ServerName`` is set to for the ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: I'm still getting the error:"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Thanks again, but the "can't find htaccess file" error occurs when I go to www.mysite.com too

Comment: I gave permission to /var/www/<mysite> and now I have 500 error.  I think I can handle it.  thanks for your help

Comment: Any directories need to be accessible to the Apache user. Normally stuff under ``/var/www`` is so didn't expect that to be the problem. It is more obvious when people stick stuff under a home directory as they aren't generate accessible.